# How do I use the variables from rlang::UQS in a custom function?

Tags: r, rlang

I am still trying to understand quosures in R, but I do not understand why the substitution in the function below fails.

```
my.toggle <- function(toggle) {
  if (toggle) {
    print("yes")
  } else {
    print("no")
  }
}

fn.args <- list(toggle = T)
my.toggle(rlang::UQS(fn.args))  # fails
# Error in if (toggle) { : argument is not interpretable as logical

rlang::quo(my.toggle(rlang::UQS(fn.args)))  # but this is the right function call
# <quosure: global>
# ~my.toggle(toggle = TRUE)
```

It seems like calling `my.toggle(rlang::UQS(fn.args))` should be equivalent to `my.toggle(toggle = T)` (and, indeed, that's what you get when you wrap the function call in `quo`), but the function does not execute correctly.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to evaluate your quosure, like so:

```
library(rlang)

eval_tidy(quo(my.toggle(UQS(fn.args))))

[1] "yes"
[1] "yes"
```

(Why does it print twice? This is an artefact of `print()`: `print` normally returns its argument, *invisibly*. It seems evaluating implicitly toggles visibility, so the return value prints again. If you just replace `print("yes")` with `(print("yes"))` (toggling visibility manually with parens), the behavior is consistent again with `my.toggle(toggle = TRUE)`). I wouldn't worry about it too much).

As to why you get the error: `UQS()` returns a list, specifically: a `Dotted pair list of 1`: `$ toggle: logi TRUE`. You could hack around with  `my.toggle(UQS(fn.args)[["toggle"]])`.